# Committing the code on Subversion (first time)

Tags: svn, ssh, commit, svn-checkout

I am new on Subversion. I have to commit a code on subversion and this is the first time that I am doing this. So my mentor told me to put username on his server using SSH. I did this by following code:

`amit@<URL>` and it works fine.

Now he asked to commit the code and he give me url, but he said me to create a folder first by username which you have got at the time of SSH i.e. amit.

How I create a folder on svn link and then how to commit the project.

Comment: did you check out the code from any URL? I mean your mentor gave you any URL to check out?

Comment: Refer this in future http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.pdf

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First checkout that repository by

```
svn checkout <Your URL> svn
```

Now `cd` to **svn** folder, create username folder(amit) in **svn** folder and commit:

```
svn commit -m"username folder is created."
```

Now copy your files in that folder(**amit** in your case). Now you have to add each new file or new folder:

```
svn add filename
svn add foldername
```

Now you can commit these files to server:

```
svn commit -m"Some new files are added."
```

**Note:** *Text after `-m` are comments and you can change it according to your needs.*

Comment: Hey Naveed , Thanks for the reply...but the folder which i have to commit is on my mail. and through some tutorial i added svn folder in my file system. So now the struncture is look like :

/home/amit/svn

and now i am created an another folder name " amit " and put my code on amit (from mail)...and now it's look like :

/home/amit/svn/amit

Now i have to run the command 
svn checkput http://chianti.ucsd.edu/svn/csplugins/trunk/soc/
above URL is where i have to put the code after creating a new folder....

Comment: Now copy these mail folders in your svn folder. After that open terminal and go to that svn folder. Now when you `svn status`, You will see newly added files with question mark(?). Add each file by `svn add filename`. After adding commit it by `svn commit -m"your comments"`

Comment: Before commit, You have to add new folder after copying it in svn folder. Read my answer again.

Comment: Naveed, I just download the folder and copied to my svn directories and when i run the svn status command on terminal .It show this SVN : warning: '.' is not a working copy what next? 

sORRY FOR ASKING THIS SILLY QUESTION .BUT IT'S VERY URGENT :)

Comment: The reason of this warning is that you are not in your svn directory. Go to that svn directory first and then use `svn status`

Comment: same ....my subversion directories is /home/amit/svn
and i created a folder name amit in that
/home/amit/svn/amit
and now i cpoied all the content from mail to amit
and currently i am in the directory : /home/amit/svn
and now i run the command svn status...and i found that warning again :(

Comment: OK. Did you checkout this **svn** folder using `svn checkout` OR you created it your self ???

Comment: I refer this link : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion
and created a svn folder by this command:
 $ sudo svnadmin create /home/svn/amit

Comment: and now in amit i have so much folder :
conf
DB
hook and e.t.c

Comment: You said that someone gave you a URL and asked you to commit your code there. So you have to checkout that URL by `svn checkout <URL> svn`. Now a new `svn` folder will be created on your system. Now you will create a folder(amit) in that svn folder. Then copy your files to amit folder. Now got to `/home/amit/svn/amit` on terminal window and run `svn status`

Comment: Please read my answer again and follow steps from the beginning carefully.

Comment: Naveed, I followed your above comment

i did checkout. It created a svn folder in my file system then i created a new folder named amit..then i copy all the data to this folder and then i run the sudo svn status .It shows same warning

Comment: OK. What is your current location(folder) in terminal window ??

Comment: /home/amit/svnlatest/svn/amit
svnlatest is i created a new folder 
svn is that i download by doing checkout i.e. svn checkout <URL> svn
and i created a new folder amit inside this svn

Comment: You said that you are in `/home/amit/svnlatest/svn/amit` and you downloaded `svnlatest` folder by `svn checkout`. Then `svn status` or `svn info` commands should work.. If these are not working it is strange.

Comment: yeh !! it works :)

i tried sudo...now what i have to naveed ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I did...It shows several files (which is in folder)like this :::::::::

A  (bin)  amit/build/classes/exportasxgmmltrial/Main.class

Comment: Its Ok. Now run `svn status` again and you will see `A amit`

Comment: It shows several files with :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::A       amit/build.xml

Comment: Its Ok... Now your code is ready to commit to server.. Run `svn commit -m"Amit folder is added."`

Comment: yeh !! Thanks a alot ... :)

You make my day :)

Comment: Haha.. Now told your mentor that you have done your job :) Now you can accept this answer if it helped you...

Comment: Hey naveed...It show this error

svn: The log message is a pathname (was -F intended?); use '--force-log' to override

Comment: So the code is not committed ?? what `svn status` says now ??

Comment: A       amit/src/exportasxgmmltrial/js/json2.js
A       amit/src/exportasxgmmltrial/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
A       amit/build.xml

look like this

Comment: It means your all files are not committed successfully. I saw this error first time. We have to search about this ??

Comment: Try `svn commit --force-log -F`

Answer (score 4):

**Magic!! :)**

If you already have a project that you started working on but it's not an svn working copy yet.

**The simplest way ever:**

Navigate to the project folder in the terminal using cd and type:

> svn co http://svn.mine.com/svn/app_ios/trunk/ .

then:

> svn add --force .

then:

> svn commit -m "first commit"

Comment: what about `svn add * --force` ?

Comment: why star? . works. I dont know wht is * mean. but dot mean current folder. Try it. It wont harm.

Comment: Alright, * will be less painful. It will add everything (from any kind) in your project directory.

Answer (score 2):

`svn ci` is as good as using `svn commit`

Answer (score 0):

Create the folder in your home filesystem and commit the entire thing to the server.

ex:
 amit/your_project_folder/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but i would try this:

- `svn mkdir armit@<host>/<your_folder>`
- `svn checkout armit@<host>/<your_folder>`
- copy your files into `<your_folder>` in local
- `svn commit <your_folder>`

Comment: Ordering is changed dude------------- First u will checkout then you will create directory using mkdir :)

Comment: It also works my way dude, you can create folder on remote (if you have permission to), checkout, fill with files and commit. Not saying it is the best way, but "a way" :)

Comment: Ok dude! But it simply seems kinda awkward first to create a directory in repo then checkout. First you will not have a proper log message, I mean how will you audit from where a specific folder came into picture? I mean got my concern? Though you have already said IT IS NOT THE BEST WAY, BUT A WAY

Comment: Ok i understand your point; i suppose i have done this from time to time to avoid checking out the whole project/repository, when the only thing i wanted to do was adding a svn folder from a local temporary folder... kinda :D (maybe it's a "dirty" trick hehe)

Answer (score 0):

I had to send my code to other svn url from my svn. What I did

1 Take checkout of destination svn url in one place (Where i need to push my code)

> svn co destination_svn_url

2 Now, I have my code. I deleted .svn folder(hidden) from my code using following command to avoid conflict between versions

> rm -rf `find . -type d -name .svn`

3 Now I copied my code(folder) and paste it to destination folder i.e in step 1 and run the following command

> svn add folder_path_i_paste

4 Now commit the code.

> svn commit -m"Code pushed"

Answer (score 0):

//First add working copy

- svn co your url
- svn add * --force
- svn commit -m "first commit"

//Remove frameworks such as google places, Google maps, Google maps core because these cause error while uploading data.