# How to commit code to SVN from xcode 6.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, svn, svn-server

Can anyone please tell me if **any possibility  to commit every update to SVN from xcode 6.4** or Mac OS X 10.10 via terminal codes or if any reference links for configuration of Xcode6.4  project with svn..

Currently I am using [This](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/edguide/chapter03.html#ch03-add) to commit or check out from svn but is I am facing bit complicated to get update via `svn co 'path' --username name` from svn ..If anyone are using SVN with Graphical user interface,please tell me the procedure or if any reference links

Comment: What do you mean by "update every commit to SVN"?

Comment: Sorry, misspelled .edited  the question

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/6409393/849486 . You can check for some GUI tools too, if needed.

Comment: You can try SmartSVN.

Comment: @ Sarath Neeravallil , I will check this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not sure what you mean by "update every commit", but if all you need is to be able to commit modified files manually from the Xcode user interface, it seems to work for me without any plugins. In the Project Navigator, all modified files are marked with M letter. If I right-click such a file (or multiple files), I can select Source Control -> Commit "filename.m" option. See a screenshot:

[image: SVN commit/update/discard option in XCode]

Note, to get SVN integration with Xcode working, you should open Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts tab and add your SVN account there (+ button in the bottom left corner -> Add Repository).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try [svnX](https://code.google.com/p/svnx/). I used this tool to commit and update my code before.

Comment: I have tried to use this already, but it was showing an error to me "Path" is not an working copy,even though it is working with terminal